# How to optimize mysql fulltext union search?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am making a mysql fulltext search.

my database table `article1` has `~18000` articles, `article2` has `~7000` articles, `article3` has `~13000` articles. FIELD cat is a INDEX field

Now I want to make a union search. there are 5 groups words put into 3 table, match out the results. But the process time is `3.1213495136 seconds`. (I add `microtime()` to see how much time it will cost). Is there any way to optimize mysql fulltext union search? Thanks.

```
(SELECT title,content,date FROM article1 WHERE 
(cat='novel' AND MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Mary +Barnard' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(cat='novel' AND MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Patricia +Beer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(cat='novel' AND MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Aphra +Behn' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(cat='novel' AND MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Judy +Blume' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(cat='novel' AND MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Elizabeth +Bowen' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
UNION 
(SELECT title,content,date FROM article2 WHERE 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Mary +Barnard' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Patricia +Beer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Aphra +Behn' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Judy +Blume' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content)AGAINST ('+Elizabeth +Bowen' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
UNION 
(SELECT title,content,date FROM article3 WHERE 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Mary +Barnard' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Patricia +Beer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Aphra +Behn' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Judy +Blume' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
OR 
(MATCH (title,content)AGAINST ('+Elizabeth +Bowen' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to an external full-text search server such as sphinxsearch.com. From my experience sphinx will be x times faster than mysql full text search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should do is to add

```
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10
```

into each subquery as you don't need more than 10 results in the end.

There also must be indexes on fields "date" in all tables.

```
alter table "TABLENAME" add index date_idx(date);
```

ADDITIONALLY:

You may shorten and slightly speed it query by changing search terms to form: "() | ()"

```
(SELECT title,content,date FROM article1 WHERE 
(cat='novel' AND MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('(+Mary +Barnard) | (+Patricia +Beer) | (+Aphra +Behn) | (+Judy +Blume) | (+Elizabeth +Bowen)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION 
(SELECT title,content,date FROM article2 WHERE 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('(+Mary +Barnard) | (+Patricia +Beer) | (+Aphra +Behn) | (+Judy +Blume) | (+Elizabeth +Bowen)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION 
(SELECT title,content,date FROM article3 WHERE 
(MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('(+Mary +Barnard) | (+Patricia +Beer) | (+Aphra +Behn) | (+Judy +Blume) | (+Elizabeth +Bowen)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10)
Order By date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @Andriy Bohdan, excuse me, is it necessary change fields "date" into `INDEX`. every article date is different. Is it can help the query more quickly? Thanks.

Comment: @cj333 yes, it really can help.

Comment: It's possible that index on date doesn't give any effect. The best way to know is to test query with index and without it. To see if index helps or not, you may run EXPLAIN <query> and check if mysql uses index on date or not.

Comment: @Andriy Bohdan, right, first I add `Order By date DESC LIMIT 10` in every union, it save `0.1+ seconds`. Then `alter table "TABLENAME" add index date_idx(date);` the total time is `1.8+` seconds. But I still want to wait if there has any way make more opitimize. Thank u very much.

Comment: @cj333 added one more hint how to make it faster. Anyway if this query is run often it can make sense to use specialized full text engine such as sphinxsearch.com (lucene can work too).

Comment: @Andriy Bohdan, now i have 3 tables, nearly 40,000 articles. but if in the future, my articles increase into `1,000,000+` articles. I can not image how long should I wait. I do not want use third part full text engine, but if there has a third part free `db` which can run faster than mysql, I will try. have u used `mongodb` or others?

Comment: Mysql will not work good for 1 mln of articles. MongoDB has not much to do with full text search. From my experience sphinx is able to handle mlns of records really fast and it can take less than 1 day to setup it and start using in production, but of course it's up to you.

Comment: @Andriy Bohdan, I am sorry, I have not noticed your updated answer. Use ` "() | ()"` would raise more speed. now it only need `0.6+s`. wonderful~ Thanks, I think your answer is the best to mysql. give you the bounty :)

Comment: opps, `You may award your bounty in 13 hours.
(click on this box to dismiss)` maybe wait to tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your union would be to carry these out as separate searches. If you order your criteria by relevance, the first set is your best; return partial results and only if there's fewer than 10, try the next match, etc.

Then the query is fast for the end-user, return results in relevance order, and don't waste MySQL resources getting unwanted data. If the user asks for more, a longer, inefficient query can run, but is meaningful then.